# Silverstripe 3 - LinkingMode() for Dataobject

Tags: silverstripe

I created this function to show dataobjects as page

```
// DISPLAY ITEM AS PAGE
public function produkt(SS_HTTPRequest $request) {
    $urlSegment = $this->request->param('URLSegment');
    $item = ShopItem::get()->filter('URLSegment', $urlSegment)->first();

    if( $item ) {
        $data = array(
            'Item' => $item,
            'Title' => $item->Title,
            'Parent' => Shop::get()->First(),
            'Controller' => $this,
            'URLSegment' => $item->URLSegment
        );
        return $this->customise($data)->renderWith(array('ShopItem', 'Page'));
    } else {
        return $this->httpError(404);
    }
}
```

That's my YML File

```
---
Name: productRoute
After: 'framework/routes#coreroutes'
---
Director:
  rules:
    'onlineshop//produkt/$URLSegment!': 'Shop_Controller'
```

The function is on my Shop_Controller. and the Dataobjects are shown under onlineshop/produkt/blablabla-1

That works fine but in the navigation the link "Onlineshop" is not highlight as section.

I think I need to put the "LinkinMode()" function in my dataobject. But I don't know what the function should contain. return section current or link doesen't work.

Can someone help me?

thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

You just want to highlight "*Onlineshop*" which is a Page in your SiteTree, right?

If so, just override the `LinkingMode()` method inside that Class (extending `SiteTree`) and make it return `section` or `current` for your custom route being active...

You would just need that method on the DataObject itself if you would like to show each DataObject in the Navigation and highlighted when active.

see http://www.ssbits.com/tutorials/2010/dataobjects-as-pages-part-1-keeping-it-simple/